# Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting

So I am in vscode on typescript 2.5.3 and the following code:

```
export function isHttpHeaders ( headers: HttpHeaders | undefined ):
headers is HttpHeaders {
    return !!headers && !!headers.get && !!headers.set
}

function headersToHeadersSpec ( options?: RequestOptionsArgs ):
 Headers | undefined {

  const { headers } = options as RequestOptionsArgs

  if ( isHttpHeaders( headers ) ) {
    const reqHeaders = new Headers()
    headers.forEach( reqHeaders.set.bind( reqHeaders ) )
    return reqHeaders
  } else {
    return undefined
  }
}
```

When I attempt to compile, for some reason the line `headers.forEach( reqHeaders.set.bind( reqHeaders ) )` is complaining that the headers value is possibly undefined. Shouldn't the type guard guarantee that the value is not undefined?

Comment: Are you sure there is no `undefined` in `HttpHeaders` definition, something like `type HttpHeaders = Array<...> | undefined`

Comment: @julesRandolph HttpHeaders is an interface and has many optional properties.

Comment: I could not reproduce with a slightly modified version where I locally define the interfaces and classes you use.

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/6UG6ZgHqZMctu34UUTpqMR

Comment: Can you reproduce with my version ?

Comment: @JulesRandolph not sure how to run it and see. But here is soemthing closer to what I have locally https://paste.ofcode.org/KisvbNSCra8Axx27hrJrkz

Comment: I found your issue : the reason is that `forEach` property is optional (given the post-pended`?`) in interface `HttpHeaders`.
As a sidenote, it is weird that your guard function checks for optional properties to assert the passed object is of type `HttpHeaders`.

Comment: @JulesRandolph yep that definitely fixed it thanks! and I set the set and get to non optional as you are correct it was weird.

Comment: If you're OK I'll post a short answer and you can accept it ! Just edit your post and post your interface definition of `HttpHeaders` if you will :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from your definition of `HttpHeaders` which sets `forEach` as an optional member.

To fix the error, just label-it non-optional by removing the `?` :

```
interface HttpHeaders {
  get?: string
  set?: string
  forEach (Function): void
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have `option?` which means *the parameter is optional*, it would allow `options` to be undefined.  Even if you have code in other functions that check the value, typescript isn't smart enough to look at that code and figure out what it does.  Your code is not Compile-Time safe, but may be Run-Time safe.

Comment: Understood but the typeguard should return a boolean in the if statement and thus casting the value of headers. Which should tell ts that inside that block this value is garuanteed to be the expected non undefined value, correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's Run-Time checking, you should always do that as a good coder because you never know if someone else does something to break it.  However it is not Compile-Time safe, that is, the compiler doesn't know what the code does so it thinks it could be undefined.